# CentOS and Stop Shell Script running on screen

Tags: shell, centos, scripting

I'm trying to automatize my system,
actually using CentOS 7.

Every time I restart the machine I need to do:

```
screen -S bun
```

then on that screen I use:

```
/home/suite/bun/bun.sh
```

Nice until that.
Sometimes I need to stop that script.
Using **SSH Secure Shell Client** I press *Control + Z* for stop that script,
fix something and start again.

The problem is here:
I did notice I can do:

```
screen -dmS bun/home/suite/bun/bun.sh
```

Which is wonderfull, but when I need to fix something I cant stop the script using *Control + Z* it just show **^Z** but the script still running.

Is there a way that can I stop the script?

Answer (score 0):

You're starting `screen` in detached mode.  i.e. it runs in the background, not attached to the current terminal.

If you need to interact with anything running in that screen session, you have to attach to it first.  For example:

```
screen -D -RR bun
```

You should then be able to suspend your `bun.sh` script with **^Z**

Comment: It doesnt work for me bud